# Folder cannot be moved in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Whenever I try to upload a theme through Wordpress it says:

> The uploaded file could not be moved to C:\wamp\www\tweet\wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/07.

I googled a lot and many peope suffer the same problem while upload the image in gallery, it is basically of permission but in my case I checked out the permissions very well.

If I try to upload any other theme it works well.

**Edit** 
I am wondering if there is concept of template in WP,I can see some files with extenion `.tpl`

Comment: Is this a local install of WordPress?  What exact steps are you taking? Is the theme zipped?

Comment: @Batfan yes it is on wamp,The steps are perfect as i told other themes are uploaded,Yes it is zipped

Comment: You probably don't have write access to your local folder.

Comment: The user that the webserver is running as needs write access.

Comment: @JohnRobinson No permissions was fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you permissions are perfect and still you are facing the problem then the only way is to copy the zipped file into theme folder and then activate the theme from your Admin Panel

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of my "dashboard" page I have an option of clicking on the "RESET OPTIONS NOW". When I did this I was then able to load my logo.